# urlrewriter not rewriting URL correctly

Tags: java, jsp, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using [urlrewriter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to rewrite a url like this:

```
<rule>
   <from>^/([a-zA-Z\-]+)/</from>
   <to>/index.jsp?category=$1</to>
</rule>
```

So if I click on a link like this `http://localhost:8080/website/categoryname/` it actually goes to the webpage `http://localhost:8080/website/index.jsp?category=categoryname`.

The problem I'm having is if I click a link for category1 first it correctly rewrites the URL as `http://localhost:8080/website/category1/`.

But when I click on a link for category2 whilst on the category1 webpage it appends onto the existing rewritten URL like this: `http://localhost:8080/website/category1/category2/`.

It should look like this `http://localhost:8080/website/category2/`.

This is my web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Why is it not rewriting correctly?

Comment: Because it is **not** rewriter that handles that. It is your basic relative URL addressing... You should write your links correctly

Comment: @GermannArlington Sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I had to remove the last forward slash `/` in the link on the webpage and in the `from` part of the rule.

```
<rule>
   <from>^/([a-zA-Z\-]+)$</from>
   <to>/index.jsp?category=$1</to>
</rule>
```